# Calculate: $\int 3^{3^{3^{x}}}3^{3^{x}}3^{x} dx$

Tags: integration

How to calculate following integration?

$$\int \left(3^{3^{3^{x}}}3^{3^{x}}3^{x}\right)\ dx$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $$I(a) = \int a^{a^{a^x}} a^{a^x} a^x dx$$
Set $a^{a^{a^{x}}} = t$. We then have $a^{a^{a^x}} a^{a^{x}} a^x \log^3(a) dx = dt$. Hence,
$$I(a) = \int \dfrac{dt}{\log^3(a)} = \dfrac{t}{\log^3(a)} + \text{constant} = \dfrac{a^{a^{a^{x}}}}{\log^3(a)} + \text{constant}$$

Answer (score 5):

Substituting $u=3^x, du=\ln 3\cdot 3^x dx$, we get

$$\frac{1}{\ln 3}\int 3^{3^u}3^u du$$

If you keep doing this, can you see how to finish?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\left(3^{3^{3^{x}}}3^{3^{x}}3^{x}\right)\mathrm{d}x=\left(\ln\,3\right)^{-3}3^{3^{3^{x}}}$$

Comment: While technically correct, you don't answer the actual question _how_ to calculate that integral...

Answer (score -1):

in the given problem,

all u need to do is

Substitute $t=3^{3^x}$

then you will get ur answer